# How can i convert this code to swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
NSstring *strURL =[NSString stringwithformat:@"http://localhost/example/login.php?email=%@&password=%@",email.text,password.text];
```

how do I convert this to Swift?

Comment: Some how help you https://objectivec2swift.com/?ref=producthunt#/converter

Answer (score 3):

```
var strURL = "http://localhost/example/login.php?email=\(email.text)&password=\(password.text)"
```